# how i can click item in staggered gridview in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I click item in `StaggeredGridView` in Flutter?
I want to add `Navigator` and send link photo to another screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Staggered View",
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          itemCount: 15,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
            height: 120.0,
            width: 120.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=$index')  ,

                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            ),
          ),
          staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
          new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 3 : 2),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below code. You need to  use [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html). Then push it in another class. please check my answer for details.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Staggered View",
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          itemCount: 15,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        details("https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=$index")),
              );
            },
            child: new Container(
              height: 120.0,
              width: 120.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=$index'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
              new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 3 : 2),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class details extends StatelessWidget {
  details(this.image);

  String image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: Image.network(image),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the many questions
How can I change the image file link to an uploaded file on the Mega Cloud, for example?

Comment: Or how do I put a list of items inside, put the image links inside it
I hope you understood what I want

Comment: Sorry i dont! What you exactly want?

Comment: I want change link inside image network to List String

Comment: you need to get list image from server or any class

Comment: Yes how i can display image from List uri

Comment: you can check https://gist.github.com/salimmurshed/12720acdffbfe6329b302b514dcfe1b9

Comment: Thank you alot

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the widget that is returned by the `itemBuilder` with a widget that can handle tap events, such as a `GestureDetector` or an `InkWell`:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // call Navigator here
  },
  child: Container(
    height: 120.0,
    width: 120.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=$index'),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    ),
  ),
),
```

More information on [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) or [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) can be found in the docs